# Picture Box and Form Transparency

Tags: vb.net

Maybe I am missing something, but is it the case that when you set a pictureboxes background to transparent, all it really does is set it to the same color as the forms background?

What I am trying to do is draw an animation for the benefit of this, a bouncing ball - which I paint on the form, then overlay that with a picture frame. End result should be a bouncing ball in a picture frame, I should mention that the picture frame does not have a straight edge, so it is not possible to arrange 4 picture boxes in a frame. The ball needs to vanish behind the frame to change color and then magically bounce back out.

I have tried:

1.Setting the picture box background to pink and then key out the same pink, this basically cuts away everything, including that which is behind the picture box
2.Setting the picture box to transparent, this just displays the picture box background as the same color as the forms background.
3.I have tried painting the image in a rectangle, this had the same effect as drawing it in a picture box.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I am wondering if there is any other ways I could try or if someone has made a custom control or library that supports transparency?

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Could you post some code or a picture? Even if you post code of those bouncing balls *without* transparent background, it would be much easier for us to help you than having no code at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Panel with the background image set. This is because; as you said: the transparent option only takes the backcolour of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more in depth research I solved this by drawing both the images to the form using PaintEventArgs and me.paint

Making each image transparent using:

```
Dim TestImage as Bitmap
TestImage.MakeTransparent(<Transparency Color>)
```

Thank you to both of you for your replies though.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... If You want to use Picturebox and get a transparent image, 
Try to set picturebox's background as your 'Ball' (probably you need an image editor).
and set picturebox transparent. It worked for me (VS Express 2010) once.